# File "/WEB-INF/displaytag.tld" not found exception

Tags: jsp

I am trying jstl code. This is the code from web.xml

```
<jsp-config>
<taglib>
    <taglib-uri >http://displaytag.sf.net</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>WEB-INF/displaytag.tld</taglib-location> 
</taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

And in my jsp file I have written following line:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>
```

I dont know anything about jstl. And I got this code while searching jstl example on net.As per the note on the net this code is working. But I am getting following exception :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: File "/WEB-INF/displaytag.tld" not found
```

The full stack trace :

```
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:51)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:409)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:116)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:160)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:424)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:493)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1557)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:127)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:212)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:101)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:156)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:296)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:265)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:302)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

I have also included jstl.jar and standard.jar file. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: If you intend to use JSTL, then you need download and put it in your project. Take a look at a similar issue

http://www.coderanch.com/t/514610/JSP/java/absolute-uri-cannot-resolved-either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has **nothing** to do with JSTL. To learn what exactly JSTL is, check [our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info).

Displaytag is not part of JSTL. Displaytag is a completely separate taglib which needs to be [downloaded](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/download.html) from http://displaytag.sf.net. The very same site also contains [installation instructions](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/install.html).

Comment: @Nav Yes I have gone through the link but the same solution is not working for my application. I am using tomcat6.0.35